# I want to change Cmd Font Style

Tags: c++, c, cmd, window, windows-console

I want to Change Cmd Font with C - Coding.

But I don't know how to change it.

I want to change Basic font -> Terminal Font.

### This is my code

```
CONSOLE_FONT_INFOEX cfi;
cfi.cbSize = sizeof cfi;
cfi.nFont = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 0;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 16;
cfi.FontFamily = FF_DONTCARE;
cfi.FontWeight = FW_NORMAL;
wcscpy_s(cfi.FaceName,9, L"Terminal");
SetCurrentConsoleFontEx(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FALSE, &cfi);
```

My Development Environment is on Windows 10.

Comment: Works fine.  The default is already Terminal, be sure that you can see the differences.  Others are "Consolas" and "Lucida Console".  Don't lie to wcscpy_s().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with the `SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()` function, is that the width of the font is not optional.  You have to use a value which is consistent with the Y size and supported by the chosen font.

For `Terminal`, the following should work:

```
cfi.dwFontSize.X = 12;
cfi.dwFontSize.Y = 16;
```

If you want to check the font size available, you can enumerate the fonts. For example, with this small code:

```
// callback to display some infos about one font 
int CALLBACK logfont(_In_ const LOGFONT    *lplf, 
    _In_ const TEXTMETRIC *lptm,
    _In_       DWORD      dwType,
    _In_       LPARAM     lpData
    )
{
    wcout << L"Font " << (wchar_t*)lplf->lfFaceName << L" " << lplf->lfHeight<<L" "<<lplf->lfWidth <<endl;
    return 1;
}

// this callback is then used in a statement like:  
EnumFonts(GetDC((HWND)GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE)),L"Terminal", logfont, NULL);
```

For more in-depth infos about installed fonts, [this MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd162615%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) article may interest you.